# Weakened version of Fano's inequality

Tags: information-theory

How does the weakened version of the Fano's inequality $1+P_{e}\log(|X|-1) \geq H(X|Y)$ make sense because trivially $H(X|Y) \leq 1$. What am I missing?

Comment: $H(X|Y) \leq 1$ isn't true right?

Comment: I am sorry but can you please tell me why? If $H(X) \leq 1$ shouldn't the conditional entropy be less than 1 as well? (assuming |X|=2)

Comment: I think it doesn't make any sense for $|X|=2$ but for higher alphabet sets, it does

Comment: Again $H(X)\leq 1$ isn't true but $H(X) \leq \log(|X|)$ is. One can't assume $|X|=2$, it'll just be a special case.

Answer (score 0):

The standard formulation is
$$
H(X | Y) \le H({1}\{X \ne Y\}) + P(X \ne Y) \log( |\mathcal{X}| - 1)
$$
but $1\{X \ne Y\}$ is just a Bernoulli($p$) random variable for some $p$. The entropy of this RV is maximised by $p= 1/2$ and at this value the entropy is $H(\text{Bernoulli}(1/2)= 1$.